# How can I use .input-append with a .form-inline?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Twitter Bootstrap and am starting to fumble my way through its use. While certain aspects of the framework are starting to make sense I am still struggling with form styling. I am trying to setup several different sections of a form which will have elements that are styled utilizing `.form-inline`. In one such instance I am also attempting to use `.input-append` with little luck.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="well span12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12 form-inline input-append">
                <label for="assetSearch">Asset Search</label>
                <input type="search" id="assetSearch" placeholder="">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12 form-inline">
                <label for="service">Service</label>
                <input type="text" id="service" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above markup renders like this:

[image: screenshot of how the above markup renders]

As you can see "Asset Search" is not inline with the form input. If i remove the `.input-append` class from the containing div things line up. However, the search icon is no longer embedded in the text box, but instead to the right of text box.

How can I use `.form-inline` in cunjunction with `.input-append`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put inside a `input-append` (or prepend) anything else than `input`s, `button`s or `.add-on`s (this might not be exhaustive).

Try wrapping the whole thing into a `div.input-append` and let the `.form-inline` handle the floating : [Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/Hx5f7/)

```
<div class="span12 form-inline">
    <label for="assetSearch">Asset Search</label>
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="search" id="assetSearch" placeholder="" />
        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle of working alignment: http://jsfiddle.net/Jeff_Meadows/xGRtL/

The two fixes are to set `vertical-align` of `<label>` elements inside elements of class `.input-append`, and to reset the `font-size` of your element to 14px (it's set to 0 somewhere else in bootstrap).  Rather than create a rule based on `.input-append`, I created a new class that you can add to your containing element.  That way, you won't get unexpected results elsewhere.

```
.input-prepend label, .input-append label {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.fix-text-spacing {
    font-size: 14px;
}
```